# How to let user enter marker in Form to add a marker to react Map from google maps api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps-react

just as the title says, how do you let a user enter marker in Form to add a marker to react Map from google maps api

example

user want to create an event at a certain location, so they want to add a marker to the google Map via form.  they just click on the map or enter the latitude, longitude and enter the info on the event/party/etc and set datetime duration of the event.

How can this be coded in react?

Comment: I found some solution, but I want to use a react form so the user can enter party info on the location of the party ```// This event listener calls addMarker() when the map is clicked.
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
    placeMarker(e.latLng, map);
  });

  function placeMarker(position, map) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      map: map
    });  
    map.panTo(position);
  }```

Comment: This package is quite popular, easy to use and has plenty of documentation. 

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-maps

Comment: Please put new information in your question post, not in comments.